# Change the primary image dimension without touching placeholder image size in Flutter

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I have a little question about image and preloading in flutter :

How to change the fit value to cover of an image without touching the size of the placeholder ?

```
Widget primaryVideoImg(img) {
return Flex(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
      placeholder: 'res/preloader.gif',
      image: 'remote image url',
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    )))
  ],
);
```

}

As you  see in the picture bellow the placeholder take also the whole page.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Stack` and some transparent image for `placeholder` in `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` to achieve what you want.

For your code it will look something like this:

```
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

...

Stack(children: <Widget>[
        new Image.asset('res/preloader.gif', fit: BoxFit.fill),
        FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
          image: 'remote image url',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

You can make your own transparent image and attach it to the project.
Or use `kTransparentImage` presented in *transparent_image 0.1.0* plugin:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/transparent_image

I find this trick in Flutter cookbook.
For more information look on this link:
https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

Good Luck!