# How to get the dimensions of a flutter image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need calculating the aspect ration from image from width and heigth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the width and height of an image in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665955/how-do-i-determine-the-width-and-height-of-an-image-in-flutter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the primary image dimension without touching placeholder image size in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522290/change-the-primary-image-dimension-without-touching-placeholder-image-size-in-fl)

Comment: This approach allows you to bypass the asynchronous operations with images, making the process of retrieving their sizes simpler and faster.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106466/11199834

Comment: Clarify your question, an image, from Image widget or network url or assets/ Or all of them? Don't post question so blurry as it might make new comers very confused. Same your time, same everybody's time.

Answer (score 5):

If I understood you correctly, you need size of widget.
For this you have to use `GlobalKey`:

```
final _key = GlobalKey();
```

Then set the `key` when you create widget:

```
Image.asset('asset_image', key: _key,); //it can be any widget
```

And after you can get size of this widget:

```
Size size = _key.currentContext.size;
double height = _key.currentContext.size.height;
double width = _key.currentContext.size.width;
double aspectRatio = _key.currentContext.size.aspectRatio;
```

**UPD for `NetworkImage`:**

`NetworkImage` isn't a widget, it can be used in `Image`, so you can get aspect ratio as in example above:

```
Image(image: NetworkImage('url'), key: _key,);
```

Or you can get width and height from listener and calculate ratio:

```
Image(image: NetworkImage('url'))
    .image
    .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
  int width = info.image.width;
  int height = info.image.height;
});
```

Comment: I want get size of image from NetworkImage and calculate the aspect ratio

Comment: @ANTONIOVENANCIO you can get the aspect ratio by doing following: width/height. Your welcome